# Can't submit on SKStoreReviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to get users to write reviews in the app without being redirected to the app store.

So, I have added the following code to show in app rate popup to the users.

```
-(void)showRatePopupIfAvailable{

    if([SKStoreReviewController class])
        [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```

I tried both similator and device. Pop-up is viewed successfully, but I can't to click on submit button.
Is there a configuration I should also do?

Tested iOS Version : 10.3.2

[image]

Comment: check your iOS verson, whats your depolyment target

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I already checked it, iOS 10.3

Comment: SKStoreReviewController available on iOS 10.3 and above, if it is below use openURL method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Pop-up is viewed successfully, send button is not working.

Comment: ya I also faced the same issue , so I used the verson > 10.3 , its works fine for me

Comment: Is your app already available on appstore?

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Yes its available.

Comment: You should test on any version > 10.3 and also check for you method call to showRatePopupIfAvailable

Comment: @ParasGorasiya I did check on iOS 10.3.2, I added a screenshot.

Comment: Did you call this method while your app is still in development mode (e.g. TestFlight)?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Yes, this version of my application is not available on App Store.

Comment: Submit button is disabled in development mode. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review

Comment: @KosukeOgawa thanks for the answer.