# SKStoreReviewController requestReview method takes time to display and app get stuck until ReviewController presented

Tags: ios, storekit, review

I am using StoreKit for in app rating. but whenever I call SKStoreReviewController requestReview method, the app get stuck and after a while the review View presented and then app get to normal state. Why this happened and if there is any solution for it?

I have another question, is write a review is necessary (i.e) i don't want to open app store for writing a review, i want that user just submit a review and remain in the app.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this same issue. But (at least as far as I can tell) only in the debug version of my app. I have no way of fixing it. But it appears that the storekit is trying to connect to some Apple server, and sometimes that connection takes long.

And while the connection is trying to be established, the whole main queue is frozen. Nothing gets through.

I made some syslog. And at some point I see this happening:

```
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(CFNetwork)[14436] <Notice>: Task <F9F9DB85-B649-43CC-A3D6-B8E931BF9ADA>.<27> resuming, QOS(0x19)
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(CFNetwork)[14436] <Notice>: Task <F9F9DB85-B649-43CC-A3D6-B8E931BF9ADA>.<27> {strength 0, tls 4, ct 0, sub 0, sig 1, ciphers 0, bundle 1, builtin 0}
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(CFNetwork)[14436] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [29:0x280586a00]
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(CFNetwork)[14436] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [29:0x280586a00]
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(libnetwork.dylib)[14436] <Notice>: [C29 Hostname#68464834:443 tcp, url hash: 11d80191, tls] start
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(libnetwork.dylib)[14436] <Notice>: nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_locked [C29] reporting state preparing
Mar  4 18:17:37 RetepV StoreKitUIService(CFNetwork)[14436] <Notice>: Task <F9F9DB85-B649-43CC-A3D6-B8E931BF9ADA>.<27> setting up Connection 29
.
```

Then a whole lot of stuff is happening that's not related to connection C29. And the first time I see C29 pop up again is 31 seconds later:

```
Mar  4 18:18:08 RetepV StoreKitUIService(libnetwork.dylib)[14436] <Notice>: nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [C29.1 IPv4#9566630f:443 in_progress channel-flow (satisfied)] Transport protocol connected
.
```

And I had already observed that my app was frozen for about 30 seconds.

I don't see how I can fix this, it's an API call of exactly 1 line. This is something that only Apple must fix. An API function that can freeze the app for some unknown amount of time is not good.

Edit:

NOTE: My requestReview call is always made on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

> I call SKStoreReviewController requestReview method, the app get stuck
>   and after a while the review View presented and then app get to normal
>   state.

Place a breakpoint on the line where you call `requestReview` and make sure this is happening on your main thread.

> I don't want to open app store for writing a review, i want that user
>   just submit a review and remain in the app.

Per app store guidelines now, you absolutely most use this for reviews, so there is no alternative approach or customization available that you may use when submitting new & updated apps now.

You can see [here under section 1.1.7](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

I have [additional information under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review/45061556#45061556) that may be of use as well for handling review requests.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the app will get stuck when `requestReview` called with bad network.Before the review View presented,even the `hitTest` method will not get called.May be one solution is that do not call `requestReview` method in a bad network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run into the same problem. It is bad network. It is not enough to check for WIFI connection, for instance, but one also needs to check whether the connection is fast and leading to the internet. My user base is sometimes using local WIFI generated by a device to share, e.g., its screen. But it does not mean it will get you to the internet. So, the solution is to A) check that WIFI is available, and B) use an as simple as possible test to see whether one can reach anything out there. I ended up seeing whether I can reach captive.apple.com. Had to set a tough limit on the timeout interval, and now it seems to be working okish.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Apple has fixed the issue on iOS 16. As I just received a reply from Apple: "This shouldn't be an issue in recent builds. Please verify and close this feedback, if the issue is resolved for you. Thanks!" for FB8936712.