# Expo - iOS SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() not working in enterprise builds

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, expo

On iOS, I'm trying to call Expo.StoreReview.requestReview() in a stand alone app (Enterprise) and the popup is not coming up.  This works perfectly fine in the iOS Simulator.

In the iOS device settings, I confirmed that In App Ratings is indeed enabled.  Is there something else I'm forgetting or does this not work for Enterprise builds?

EDIT: Looks like there is already a similar thread here: [Why the SKStoreReviewController does not let me submit a review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I guess the enterprise build falls under point #2 in this post?

Comment: @Paulw11 True, but we distribute Enterprise builds for our testers and they need to test this feature for our next release.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's strange because it says in the documentation that calling the requestReview() method does nothing in a Testflight app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

Comment: Ok; Anyway I just added a review request to an enterprise app and rebuilt it and I get prompted to review every time; just like a development build I can't "submit" the review but I can tap the stars.

Comment: @Paulw11 huh. ok.  I will have to check it out.  Thanks!