# Rate in app not working/showing up when run from TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

I am using this code to prompt a rate us in my app:

```
if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()

} else if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/" + "MyIdHere") {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

On the simulator, the rate prompt comes up as planned, but I i run it using testflight, the rate does not come up at all. Any tips?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `SKStoreReviewController`. It doesn't appear every time you call it, except in development.

Comment: @rmaddy But how can I then test it?

Comment: Does it appear properly in development? Then it will appear, when Apple deems it should, in Test Flight and from the App Store.

Comment: @rmaddy It does appear when running on simulator, but it does not appear in TestFlight.

Comment: Running on the simulator is development. Using TestFlight is production.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, ok! Thanks

Comment: @Camile Covered this in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057452/why-the-skstorereviewcontroller-does-not-let-me-submit-a-review/45061556#45061556

Comment: @rmaddy Apple already accepted my new update, so the new app version is out in AppStore. When I try to prompt the rate popup, it doesn't pop up at all on my phone? Any ideas?

Comment: It's the same thing. The review screen isn't shown every time you ask for it. Again, read the documentation for SKStoreReviewController and the requestReview method.

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's documentation this API has no effect in `testflight` and you should never link this API to any `user action` because Apple reserves the right to show or not the prompt even when you call this API, also the prompt will only be displayed to a user a maximum of `three times` within a `365-day period`

> Note
>
> When you call this method while your app is in development mode, a
> rating and review request view is always displayed so you can test the
> user interface and experience. However, this method has no effect when
> you call it in an app that you distribute using TestFlight.

If you need to call manually on any user action please use the code below:

```
@IBAction func requestReviewManually() {
    // Note: Replace the XXXXXXXXXX below with the App Store ID for your app
    //       You can find the App Store ID in your app's product URL
    guard let writeReviewURL = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXXX?action=write-review")
        else { fatalError("Expected a valid URL") }
    UIApplication.shared.open(writeReviewURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Please find more details about the API here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview

and also the best practice for using it here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: April 2023 and i can validate that this is the case. You can check it on the simulator but not in the app distributed via Testflight. Which makes a lot of sense.