# SKStoreReviewController with writing review options

Tags: swift, review

I have checked this link:
https://apptopi.jp/2018/01/07/ios11-in-app-review/#i-1

And I want to make this dialog.
https://apptopi.jp/wp-content/uploads/cf48db83-f3b6-42d5-abdb-94ee93ba49da.jpeg

But I can not do it with "SKStoreReviewController".
Does it be deprecated by Apple ?

PS: Sorry, I don't have permission to post image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061556/6576315

Comment: @RTXGamer 
Please see in this video.
https://streamable.com/q56yuy
After rating, they can add review. I can not find the same thing from website.